# read first line from .gz compressed file without decompressing entire file

Tags: shell-script, logs, gzip

I have a huge log file compressed in .gz format and I want to just read the first line of it without uncompressing it to just check the date of the oldest log in the file.

The logs are of the form:

```
YYYY-MM-DD Log content asnsenfvwen eaifnesinrng
YYYY-MM-DD Log content asnsenfvwen eaifnesinrng
YYYY-MM-DD Log content asnsenfvwen eaifnesinrng
```

I just want to read the date in the first line which I would do like this for an uncompressed file:

```
read logdate otherstuff < logfile.gz
echo $logdate
```

Using zcat is taking too long.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Piping `zcat`’s output to `head -n 1` will decompress a small amount of data, guaranteed to be enough to show the first line, but typically no more than a few buffer-fulls (96 KiB in my experiments):

```
zcat logfile.gz | head -n 1
```

Once `head` has finished reading one line, it closes its input, which closes the pipe, and `zcat` stops after receiving a `SIGPIPE` (which happens when it next tries to write into the closed pipe). You can see this by running

```
(zcat logfile.gz; echo $? >&2) | head -n 1
```

This will show that `zcat` exits with code 141, which indicates it stopped because of a `SIGPIPE` (13 + 128).

You can add more post-processing, *e.g.* with AWK, to only extract the date:

```
zcat logfile.gz | awk '{ print $1; exit }'
```

(On macOS you might need to use `gzcat` rather than `zcat` to handle gzipped files.)

Answer (score 5):

You could limit the amount of data you feed to `zcat` (or `gzip -dc`), then ask for the first line:

```
head -c 1000 logfile.gz | zcat 2>/dev/null | head -1 | read logdate otherstuff
```

Adjust the `1000` if that doesn't capture enough data to get the entire first line.

Comment: Shouldn't zcat+head be enough? The head process would exit when done, causing zcat to receive a PIPE signal and quit...

Comment: Sure; it may fill the pipe, so we've limited the damage in either case, but I liked the idea of throttling it "manually", in response to limiting the amount gzip deals with. I do like the idea of asking `head` to get one line from the pipe, though -- removes the guessing about how many bytes to ask `head` for.

Comment: I just need the first few characters before a space. So why would it be necessary to adjust the number of characters to get the entire line? @JeffSchaller

Comment: @PratikMayekar, if you chose too small a value, you may not get the entire first line. Since you just want the first 10-ish bytes, I chose something arbitrarily larger than 10.

Comment: `head -c 1000 logfile.gz | zcat 2>/dev/null | head -1` worked fine

`head -c 50 logfile.gz | zcat 2>/dev/null | head -1` gave no output. Why is that @JeffSchaller

Comment: I suspect there's a gzip header that you're not yet reading past.

Answer (score 5):

To just match a date from the 1st line of a zipped file - `zgrep` solution:

```
zgrep -m1 -o '^[^[:space:]]*' logfile.gz
```

This will output the first `YYYY-MM-DD` for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first line without decompressing the file:

```
gunzip -c logfile.gz | awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}'
```

That will send the compressed data to standard output without decompressing it and `awk` will print only the first line.